# Javascript onkeydown percent or five number

Tags: javascript, numbers, onkeydown

Is there any way to find out if the user pressed the percent key or 5 number? It has the same keycode in FireFox.

Answer (score 14):

You can check for modifier keys provided by the event object. `event.shiftKey` is for your specific use case. In addition there are the `event.altKey`, `event.ctrlKey` and `event.metaKey` (for windows key in windows and command key in MAC keyboards) properties of the event.
In a code example you would have to perform the check inside your keyCode handler:

```
var NUMBER_FIVE = 53;
element.onkeydown = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == NUMBER_FIVE) {
        if (event.shiftKey) {
            // '%' handler
        } else {
            // '5' handler
        }
    }
};
```

In addition when using `event.keyCode` you are handling what the user pressed on the keyboard. If you want to be checking for *specific ASCII characters* then you can use `event.charCode` instead because this event property tells you what character the user is inputting instead of telling you what the user is pressing on the keyboard. [Here's a complete guide for this on quirksmode.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)

Comment: Thank you. didn't know about that. I'm gonna check it out.

Comment: Well this was very helpful but I'm fighting with another issue... that is the Alt Gr + 4 (twice) or this ¨ character..

Comment: @user1729203 Well you would have to handle event.keyCode being 100 (num lock) and event.altKey being true.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `keydown`, 5 and % are the same keyCode. The event object also has a [`shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.shiftKey) boolean property that will tell you if the user is holding shift.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 53) {
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            // they pressed %
        } else {
            // they pressed 5
        }
    }
};
```

If you want to use `keypress`, they are two different keyCodes:

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 53) {
        // they pressed 5
    }

    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        // they pressed %
    }
};
```

[This site](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html) is good for testing keyCodes.

Answer (score 0):

Checking shiftKey value: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94VA4/1/)

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if( e.keyCode == 53 ){
      if(e.shiftKey){
        // %  pressed

     }
     else{
       // 5 pressed
     }
  }

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I test for both the keyCode and the value of the character being entered.

```
$(document).on({
 keypress: function(event){
   var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
   var mFive = String.fromCharCode(event.which); 
   if ((charCode == 53) && (mFive === "5")){
       return true;
   }else if ((charCode == 53) && (mFive !== "5")){
       return false;
   }
 });
```